# openfortivpn connection progress stops after "Connected to gateway"

Tags: vpn-client

Trying to connect SSL VPN at work from Linux (Mint) machine. Works OK from Windows 10 using  embedded client.
On Mint I'm trying to use openfortivpn (used different versions: 1.6.1 and 1.14.1 on Mint 19.3 and 1.12.1 on Mint 20.1)

```
>> openfortivpn host.name:443 --username=user --insecure-ssl -v
DEBUG:  openfortivpn 1.14.1
DEBUG:  revision unavailable
DEBUG:  Loaded config file "/etc/openfortivpn/config".
VPN account password: 
DEBUG:  Config host = "host.name"
DEBUG:  Config realm = ""
DEBUG:  Config port = "443"
DEBUG:  Config username = "user"
DEBUG:  Resolving gateway host ip
DEBUG:  Establishing ssl connection
DEBUG:  server_addr: a.b.c.d
DEBUG:  server_port: 443
DEBUG:  gateway_addr: a.b.c.d
DEBUG:  gateway_port: 443
DEBUG:  Setting minimum protocol version to: 0x303.
DEBUG:  Gateway certificate validation succeeded.
INFO:   Connected to gateway.
```

And here it stops. No further progress. PPP interface does not appear in the system.
/etc/openfortivpn/config is empty.
Is there a way to continue and finalize a connection?

Below is an information from `nmap` about server protocols:

```
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|_  least strength: D
```

Comment: ever found a solution ?

Comment: @arzhed no, still have to switch to Windows whenever I need to use this kind of VPN.